# How to built a regexp to match optional patterns

Tags: regex

I have the following strings sample:

```
MAREMMA TOSCANA BIANCO DOC 2020 CALASOLE MONTEMASSI0,750 
CHIANTI CLASSICO DOCG 2012 RISERVA ALBOLA LT.0,750
```

I need to separate in 5 parts (where I put the `|` in the following samples:

```
MAREMMA TOSCANA BIANCO DOC |2020| CALASOLE MONTEMASSI|0,750 
CHIANTI CLASSICO DOCG |2012| RISERVA ALBOLA |LT.|0,750
```

AS you can see, the fourth part is optional.

I tried some variation of this regexp on `https://regex101.com/r/NX3DE3/1`, but the `LT.` part is incorporated in the precedent one:

```
([A-Za-z ]+)((20\d\d)|(19\d\d))([A-Za-z ]*)((LT))\.?[0-9,]*
```

the `((LT))` group is optional, but if I add a `?` it run in the first example, but is not in the second and viceversa.

I would also like to `trim` the different parts, but really don't know how!

Comment: Try `(.*?)((?:20|19)\d\d)(.*?)(?:\s+(LT)\.)?(\d[\d,]*)`

Comment: What is your rule for determining where the string should be split? Do you mean  `MONTEMASSI|0,750|` rather than `MONTEMASSI|0,750`?

Comment: https://xyproblem.info/ what are you trying to solve? Is regex the solution?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you! I changed in `(.*?)((?:20|19)\d\d)(.*?)(?:\s+(LT)[\. ])?([\d,][\d,]*)` you can see the `https://regex101.com/r/NX3DE3/1`
Any idea of how to get rid of the first new two items?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
^(.*?)\s*((?:20|19)\d\d)\s*(.*?)(?:\s+(LT)[. ])?(\d[\d,]*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/quGA6h/1). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `((?:20|19)\d\d)` - Group 2: `20` or `19` and then two digits
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(.*?)` - Group 3: any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `(?:\s+(LT)[. ])?` - an optional non-capturing group matching one or more whitespaces and then capturing into Group 4 `LT` and then a space or `.`
- `(\d[\d,]*)` -  Group 5: a digit and then zero or more digits or commas.